# Conditional Query Using "AS" field

Tags: sql, select, where-clause, column-alias

```
SELECT "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."count" AS "count", "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."tag_name" AS "Tag Name",
CASE 
    WHEN "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."ngo_id" = 30 then 'SSS'
    WHEN "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."ngo_id" = 33 then 'PF'
    WHEN "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."ngo_id" = 34 then 'DS'
    ELSE 'Maybe'
END AS "NPO"
FROM "public"."mv_tags_per_org"

WHERE "NPO???" = "SSS"
```

Above you can see my code. It is currently returning exactly the output I want when you remove the "WHERE" function. I'm adding the "WHERE" function and attempting to access the new column I made called "NPO". It seems as if the column does not exist to the SQL editor, but it does exist when the query is ran. How do I access it?

Thanks!

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.  But no databases allow the use of aliases in the `where` corresponding to the `select` where they are defined.  There are four typical solutions:  repeat the expression, use a subquery, use a CTE, use a lateral join.

Comment: Do you really have a column named `"SSS"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose your query into a "table expression" so you can produce a named column. Then you can use it in the `WHERE` clause:

```
select *
from ( -- table expression 'x' starts here
  SELECT
    "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."count" AS "count",
    "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."tag_name" AS "Tag Name",
  CASE 
    WHEN "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."ngo_id" = 30 then 'SSS'
    WHEN "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."ngo_id" = 33 then 'PF'
    WHEN "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."ngo_id" = 34 then 'DS'
    ELSE 'Maybe'
  END AS "NPO"
  FROM "public"."mv_tags_per_org"
) x
WHERE "NPO" = 'SSS'
```

**Note**: "table expressions" are also called "derived tables" and "inline views" by different teams of people.

Comment: That's actually called a "derived table"

Comment: And SSS should be within Single quotes - 'SSS'

Answer (score 0):

The `WHERE` clause cannot relate to a column alias defined in the `SELECT` clause (because the former it is evaluated *before* the latter).

This does not really matter for your use case, which can be simplified as:

```
SELECT 
    "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."count" AS "count",    
    "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."tag_name" AS "Tag Name",
CASE 
    WHEN "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."ngo_id" = 30 then 'SSS'
    WHEN "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."ngo_id" = 33 then 'PF'
    WHEN "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."ngo_id" = 34 then 'DS'
    ELSE 'Maybe'
END AS "NPO"
FROM "public"."mv_tags_per_org"
WHERE "public"."mv_tags_per_org"."ngo_id" = 30
```